# SSIS SharePoint DownloadFile not closing connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, dts

I have recently created a DTS package on our SSIS servers that downloads a file from our SharePoint servers to a local destination, before extracting the Excel data to a SQL database.
This is done using a Script Task with the following code.

```
        string fileUrl = "http://enternal.website/link/to/file.xlsx";
        string tempUrl = "\\\\localserver\\directory\\file.xlsx";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        client.DownloadFile(fileUrl, tempUrl);
```

This works well, and we've been using this job for a few weeks, however it seems that today when trying to open the file from SharePoint, we get an error that 256 users are currently accessing this file and as this is the limit, no more users are allowed access.
There is only a small team working on this file so it's not likely that this is a genuine case of 256 users on it - I'm thinking that the code above downloads the file but then doesn't close the connection, meaning that every time this job runs a new user is added.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to adjust the code to close the connection after the download is complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **WebClient** Object can be disposed. See below code to dispose **WebClient** object after its use.

```
string fileUrl = "http://enternal.website/link/to/file.xlsx";
string tempUrl = "\\\\localserver\\directory\\file.xlsx";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
     client.DownloadFile(fileUrl, tempUrl);
}
```